# How to show that the limit exists for a complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

When $\lvert z\rvert \ne 1$, it is necessary to show the existence of the limit of the function

$$f(z) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{z^n-1}{z^n+1}$$

Comment: First, you should know $\lim_{n\to\infty}z^n=0$ when $|z|<1$.

Comment: When $|z|<1$, the limit is $-1$, and when $|z|>1$ the limit is $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when $|z|<1$,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}z^n=0.$$
So case one: when $|z|<1$, 
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{z^n-1}{z^n+1}=\frac{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}z^n-1}{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}z^n+1}=\frac{0-1}{0+1}=-1.$$
Case two： when $|z|>1$, then $\left|\frac{1}{z}\right|<1$,$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{z^n}=0$.
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{z^n-1}{z^n+1}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-\frac{1}{z^n}}{1+\frac{1}{z^n}}=\frac{1-\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{z^n}}{1+\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{z^n}}=\frac{1-0}{1+0}=1.$$

Comment: When $|z|=1$, the limit $lim_{n\to \infty}z^n$ does not exist except $z=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that
$$f(z) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{z^n-1}{z^n+1}=1-2\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{z^n+1}$$
if $|z|>1$ then $|z|^n\to\infty$ and
$$|\frac{1}{z^n+1}|\leq\frac{1}{|z|^n-1}\to0$$
then limit of $f$ is $\color{blue}{1}$.

If $|z|<1$ then $|z|^n\to0$ and
$$\frac{|z^n|}{|z|^n+1}\leq\left|\frac{z^n}{z^n+1}\right|\leq\frac{|z^n|}{1-|z|^n}$$
shows this limit is $0$, Therfore when $|z|<1$, 
$$f(z) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{z^n-1}{z^n+1}=2\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{z^n}{z^n+1}-1$$
and the limit is $\color{blue}{-1}$.

Comment: When $|z|<1$, the limit is $-1$, and when $|z|>1$ the limit is $1$.

Comment: yes. of course.

Comment: $|a|-|b|\leq|a\pm b|\leq|a|+|b|$

Comment: You case two is something mistake. $\frac{1}{|z|^n+1}\leq|\frac{1}{z^n+1}|\leq\frac{1}{1-|z|^n}$ only implies $|\frac{1}{z^n+1}|\to 1.$ But this does not implies $\frac{1}{z^n+1}\to 1.$

Comment: @Nosrati it looks like squeeze theorem, but something vague in the second case indeed.

Comment: @Riemann thanks, corrected.

Comment: @Nosrati Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome.

Comment: @Nosrati what if |z|=1? What happens with function f then? I'm trying to understand the behavior of the function.

Comment: @AlexanderMilogorodsky let $z=e^{i\theta}$ then the limit is $i\tan\dfrac{n}{2}\theta$ shows it is not exist for every fixed $\theta$.